# Using pointers, interfaces and custom types

Tags: go, pointers, interface

I'm trying to follow a tutorial about interfaces in Golang. It uses this code:

```
package main


import "fmt"

func main() {
  a := incrementInt(0)
  //b := incrementor(&a)
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(a.increment()) //b.increment()
  }

type incrementor interface {
  increment() int
}
type incrementInt int

func (inc *incrementInt) increment() int {
  *inc++
  return int(*inc)
}
```

The program works fine without declaring `b := incrementor(&a)`, but the tutorial used the `b` variable and used `b.increment()` instead of `a.increment()`.

What difference does this make?

Comment: This example is pretty strange and probably not helpful to understand interface types. I'd recommend working through the Tour of Go which explains this _much_ better. To answer your question: This program _demonstrates_ usage of interface. The whole purpose is _not_ to print the numbers 1 to 10 (a simple fmt.Println("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10") would do). So there is no "difference" between using a and b except that when you use a only you do not use a variable of interface type and the program no longer shows how the absolute most basic use of interface variables work.

Comment: I do not know what "tutorial" you are watching but it seems of rather low educational quality. Instead of `b := incrementor(&a)` you should be explicit and write `var b incrementor; b = &a` which makes it clear that you now have a variable of type incrementor and that you can assign &a to it. The example is really _much_ _too_ _simple_ to be sensible. Just work through the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 4):

The objective of an interface is to abstract the implementation from specific types

The line `a := incrementInt(0)` creates a variable a of type incrementInt

The line `b := incrementor(&a)` creates a variable b of type incrementor while typecasting the address of a to the interface incrementor. So if you had a generalized code it would help to understand the benefit of using interfaces for abstraction

For Example- In the code below I created an incrementFloat and add both of them to a slice of incrementor named `incs` now I can keep on creating incrementXXX types without having to change the code in the loop of the main function

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := incrementInt(0)
    b := incrementor(&a)
    c := incrementFloat32(0.0)
    d := incrementor(&c)
    incs := []incrementor{b, d}
    for _, incx := range incs {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(incx.increment())
        }
    }
}

type incrementor interface {
    increment() any
}

type incrementInt int

func (inc *incrementInt) increment() any {
    *inc++
    return int(*inc)
}

type incrementFloat32 float32

func (inc *incrementFloat32) increment() any {
    *inc += 0.1
    return float32(*inc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Go Interfaces through the lens of your tutorial, and beyond

**Interfaces** provide a way to *specify the behavior that types should have* [decoupled](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/598/decoupled) from the types, like named structs and other types derived from Go's built-in types, that implement that behavior.

#### Understanding the tutorial

##### The `incrementor` interface

The tutorial defines an interface named `incrementor` requiring a *method signature* `increment() int`.

Any type that has this method is said to *"satisfy"* the interface.

```golang
type incrementor interface {
    increment() int
}
```

##### The `incrementInt` type

It also defines a new type `incrementInt` that is **derived from** `int` - meaning it behaves exactly like an `int`, with a few exceptions *(see footnotes below):*

```golang
type incrementInt int
```

##### The `increment()` method on the `incrementInt` type

Next, the code attaches an `increment()` method to the `incrementInt` type which allows that type to satisfy the interface:

```golang
func (inc *incrementInt) increment() int {
    *inc++
    return int(*inc)
}
```

This code uses pointers to allow the `increment()` method to modify the underlying value of an `incrementInt`.

##### Declaration of the `a` variable

Next the code declares a variable named `a`, assigning it a value of zero (`0`).

```golang
a := incrementInt(0)  // Assigns value `0` to a newly-declared 
// variable `a` of type `incrementInt`.
```

Since you are new to Go you might be interested in an elaboration on my use of the term *"declaration".* If so, see the footnotes.

##### Calling `increment()` on  `a`

You could now call `increment()` on `a`, because its type declares just such a named method:

```golang
println(a.increment()) // Prints 1, then a new line
```

##### Declaration of the `b` variable

Next, we see a variable `b` of type `implementor` — an interface type — to internally contain a pointer to value of the variable `a` of type `incrementInt`:

```golang
b := incrementor(&a)
```

An `implementor` value is *allowed* to contain a pointer to an `incrementInt` value because `incrementInt` declares an `increment()` method, and that method has a [pointer receiver](https://go.dev/tour/methods/4) *(To learn more about pointer and non-pointer receivers, see the footnotes below.)*

##### Calling `increment()` on an `incrementor`

Now that we have `b` we can call `increment` on it - since by its definition, an `incrementor` is an interface that must contain an `increment()` method [*of matching signature*](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/signature-of-methods/10660).

```golang
println(b.increment()) // Prints 2 is `a.increment()` previously called
```

Thus, calling `increment()` on `b` actually calls `increment` on `a` too, as [this runnable example](https://goplay.tools/snippet/ZLmZxkQK4k9) illustrates.

The reason is that `b` contains the pointer to `a` and as such calling `increment()` on `b` causes `b` to delegate the call to the object that contains it, which is `a`.

I ***believe*** that this is essentially the same as the concept of [boxing and unboxing in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing), although I do not have enough experience with C# to say for certain. Still, maybe the association can help those who understand boxing to better understand Go's interfaces and use with the types that implement them.

#### Benefits of using interfaces

Next, let's consider **where**, **when**, and **why** you would want to use an interface in Go.

##### Using a slice of values

Let's start by elaborating on the tutorial example, using its declarations. This example creates a slice of type `incrementInt` and then loops through the slice called `increment` on each instance. Thus we see the value of interfaces in Go.

You can see the running code [in this playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/d7xA3pOA1PW):

```golang
incrInts := []incrementInt{
    incrementInt(0),
    incrementInt(10),
    incrementInt(100),
    incrementInt(1000),
}
for _, i := range incrInts {
    x := incrementor(&i)
    println(x.increment())
}
```

The above example prints the following, but does nothing to explain by you would want to use the interface. Let's remedy that.

##### Redeclaring as a slice of `implementor`

We'll first start by declaring four different types, each with their own `increment()` method *(see [playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/wKFXkck6Q1I)):*

- `incrementInt8`
- `incrementInt16`
- `incrementInt32`
- `incrementInt64`

Then we'll declare instances of each in a slice of `incrementor` and assign that slice to `incrInts`. This should work, as they all implement `increment()`, right?

```golang
incrInts := []incrementor{
    incrementInt8(0),
    incrementInt16(10),
    incrementInt32(100),
    incrementInt64(1000),
}
```

Turns out it does not work — see [playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/wKFXkck6Q1I) as above — and it throws a bunch of errors, starting with the following *(Why?):*

```
cannot convert 0 (untyped int constant) to type incrementInt8
```

Seems we are dealing with the fact that interfaces distinguish between methods on pointer received from methods on non-pointer receivers, and our four (4) values are pointer - whereas their methods are defined to work on pointers, and thus did not satisfy the interface.

##### Restructuring to pointer receivers

To get our example to work without tossing out everything about the tutorial completely, we've got a bit of work to do. Basically, we need to convert our `IncrementInt{8,16,32,64}` values into pointers to those values, so that our `increment()` methods that expect pointer receivers will satisfy the `incrementor` interface.

But to get a pointer we need to create a variable which we can point to. There are a few ways to do this, but an [anonymous function](https://www.programiz.com/golang/anonymous-function) will do *(which is basically the same as a named `New*` function, but without the name).*

Here is what our anonymous function looks like for `increment8`:

```golang
func(n int) *incrementInt8 {
    i8 := incrementInt8(n)
    return &i8 
}
```

Extrapolating out for all our types and applying to our example and we get:

```golang
incrInts := []incrementor{
    func(n int) *incrementInt8 { i8 := incrementInt8(n); return &i8 }(0),
    func(n int) *incrementInt16 { i16 := incrementInt16(n); return &i16 }(10),
    func(n int) *incrementInt32 { i32 := incrementInt32(n); return &i32 }(100),
    func(n int) *incrementInt64 { i64 := incrementInt64(n); return &i64 }(1000),
}
```

You can see in [our playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/umfF566PmGi), and it works. Finally.

#### Why all this effort?!?

Because it allows for handling different types by grouping them with a single type of interface, and then processing them all as they were all the same type - thereby decoupling code along with the benefits that provides. On the other hand, **we should not need this much complexity** to learn about interfaces. The tutorial author chose to explain interfaces using a type derived from `int`, which made explaining interfaces much more difficult than it needed to be.

##### A slightly better example

Rather than declaring `incrementInt*` types — which I cannot imagine a need for in a real-world program — let's instead define a few different inventory items.

###### Types to represent inventory items

These are still *contrived*, though not as badly contrived:

```golang
type LiquidItem struct {
    gallons int
}
type LinearItem struct {
    length int
}
type AreaItem struct {
    area int
}
```

###### A modified `incrementor` interface

We are still going to use an `incrementor` interface, because an interface of that name makes sense. However, we'll change it slightly, so that it accepts a quantity to increment by, and doesn't return its updated value. Later, we'll define another way to access the value.

```golang
type incrementor interface {
    increment(int)
}
```

###### `increment()` methods for each of our inventory item types

Next, let's add increment methods to each type - with some minor  differences just to show that we are dealing with different entities:

```golang
func (i *LiquidItem) increment(n int) {
    i.gallons += n
}
func (i *LinearItem) increment(n int) {
    i.length += n
}
func (i *AreaItem) increment(n int) {
    i.area += n
}
```

###### An interface with more obvious value: `InventoryItem`

Now we'll use another interface to associate all these items with a single type `InventoryItem`, which [embeds](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/embedding-in-go-part-3-interfaces-in-structs/) the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://go.dev/tour/methods/17) interface, which requires a `String() method` method signature *(which is how we will access our value for printing):*

```golang
type InventoryItem interface {
    incrementor
    fmt.Stringer
}
```

###### String methods illustrating something different between our types

Here are the `String()` methods:

```golang
func (i *LiquidItem) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d gallons", i.gallons)
}
func (i *LinearItem) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d linear feet", i.length)
}
func (i *AreaItem) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d square feet", i.area)
}
```

###### Using our example in `main()`:

With all that we can finally write our `main()` func:

```golang
func main() {
    incrInts := []InventoryItem{
        &LiquidItem{0},
        &LinearItem{0},
        &AreaItem{0},
    }
    for i, n := range incrInts {
        n.increment((i + 1) * 2)  // Do something more interesting that just adding 1
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", n)
    }
}
```

The above prints the following when run, and you can see it run [in the playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/_GXmzWplOxP):

```
2 gallons
4 linear feet
6 square feet
```

This use of `fmt.Stringer` might be useful for reporting the quantities currently held in inventory, and the loop doing the incrementing might be running off data transmitted regarding the quantities received by unit in a shipment from suppliers.

#### What about Generics?

Apparently the tutorial did not give an example that could illustrate the benefits of using interfaces with multiple different types. When I expanded on their `incrementInt` example, I did illustrate syntactically how interfaces could work with different integer types. But is it not a great example use of interfaces.

In theory. that example would work better with [generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) in a helper function (rather than a method) — because you can't use generics in methods in Go (yet?) — and then just passing it raw `int{8,16,32,64}` values, like so:

```golang
println(incrementInt(int8(0)))
println(incrementInt(int16(10)))
println(incrementInt(int32(100)))
println(incrementInt(int64(1000)))
```

That is possible using an `Integer` interface, but that usage of interface is a new spin on using interfaces that is both unlike using interfaces we explored above, and very limited in how those interfaces can be used.

Still, here is the code:

```golang
type Integer interface {
    int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64
}
func incrementInt[I Integer](i I)I {
    i++
    return i
}
```

You can see the generics example in [the playground](https://goplay.tools/snippet/fHf3gHQFa5t).

#### Summary

Go's interfaces are a feature that can be used in powerful ways. The aspects you mentions of the tutorial you were reading did not illustrate any of the benefits of using interfaces, it just introduced you to the superficial aspects of its syntax for a simplistic use-case.

Hopefully, however, my answer instead provided:

1. An illustration the one of the ways to use interfaces in Go in a beneficial manner, such as when you want to treat a slice of value as all being the same **type**.
2. A better use-case as an example so that the benefits of interfaces are easier to reason about.

#### Footnotes

1. Exceptions regarding `incrementInt` and `int` types
2. The variable declaration operator `:=`
3. Pointer vs. Non-pointer receivers

##### 1. Exceptions regarding `incrementInt` and `int` types

An exception for when `incrementInt` does not behave *exactly* like `int` is when you need to use a value of the exact named type `int` such as calling `strconv.Itoa()`; passing an `incrementInt` value to it **will not compile**:

```golang
var x incrementInt = 42
println("[" + strconv.Itoa(x) + "]")
```

The compile error is:

```
cannot use x (variable of type incrementInt) as int value in argument to strconv.Itoa
```

You must first *cast* your value of `incrementInt` *back* to type `int` before use.

*This* compiles, as `int(x)` casts your `incrementInt` type back to an `int` type:

```golang
var x incrementInt = 42
println("[" + strconv.Itoa(int(x)) + "]")
```

##### 2. The variable declaration operator `:=`

A *"declaration"* that uses an `:=` operator effectively means:

> *Declare a **named variable** to the **right** of `:=` to have the **type** of the **expression** on the **left**, and then **evaluate** the **expression** and **assign** its **value** to this newly-declared **variable**.*

In Go, both of these declarations mean the same thing:

```golang
a := incrementInt(0)
var a incrementInt = 0
```

Further, if the value being assigned is a [zero value](https://go.dev/tour/basics/12), then the following is also equivalent to the two forms above:

```golang
var a incrementInt
```

One final bit. You can declare variables with zero value in a `func` or method signature either as a parameter or as a return value. In the following both `input` and `output` are being declared to be of type `incrementInt` and to be initialized to a zero value, e.g. `0` in this case:

```golang
func TransformIncrementInt(input incrementInt) (output incrementInt) {
    // Do something to transform `input` and assign that value to `output`
}
```

##### 3. Pointer vs. Non-pointer receivers

The tutorial code passed a pointer to value of the variable `a` of type `incrementInt` when it declared an instance of type `incrementor` and wrapped the value of `a` into `b` using casting of a concrete value to an interface value:

```golang
b := incrementor(&a)
```

An `implementor` value is *allowed* to contain a pointer to an `incrementInt` value because `incrementInt` declares an `increment()` method having a [receiver](https://go.dev/tour/methods/4) which is a pointer to its type.

**IF** the declaration of `increment` uses a non-pointer receiver like as follows then the above would not work. *Well*, **kind of**; see below.

```golang
func (inc incrementInt) increment() int {
    *inc++
    return int(*inc)
}
```

Using an instance of `incrementInt` where `increment()` instead had a non-pointer receivery, you would need to declare `b` like so:

```golang
type incrementInt int
func (inc incrementInt) increment() int {
    *inc++
    return int(*inc)
}
a := incrementInt(0)
b := incrementor(a)
println(b.increment())
```

**HOWEVER**, this would all be moot because without getting a pointer to its receiver there is no way that `increment()` can modify the calling receiver; the non-pointer receiver inside the method is just a copy that will be thrown away after a call to `increment()` returns.